# Password protected button. c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption, passwords

Hello i am doing a void button on my point of sales. if a checkbox is checked, the user must first type a password to proceed with the button function. A new form will open and you will type the password there. However the password is encrpyted in the sql database. I have the decrypt function but i can't manage to make it work. Any help will be appreciated thank you.

The error is : `Additional information: There is no row at position 0.`

PS: I will also include the login code which decrpyt the password just fine.

Here are the codes:

Confirm button on password form:

```
 private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BENJOPC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MARISCHELLdatabase;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Password from UserAccounts where Password = @Password", con))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtAdminPassword.Text);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);

                string password = dt.Rows[0]["Password"].ToString();
                bool flagpassword = EncryptHelper.VerifyHash(txtAdminPassword.Text, "SHA512", password); // code to decrypt password

                if (flagpassword == true)
                {
                    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid password.");
                    txtAdminPassword.Clear();
                    txtAdminPassword.Focus();
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Method and how it is called on the mainform: (which is working fine)

```
 public bool voidd()
    {
        if (cbVoid.Checked == true)
        {
            POSadminPassword pap = new POSadminPassword();

            if (pap.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

and

```
 private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!voidd())
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
           //continue code
        }
    }
```

Working Login code with decrypt:

```
private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BENJOPC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MARISCHELLdatabase;Integrated Security=True";
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from UserAccounts where Username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' AND Password = '" + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + "'", cn);
        SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adptr.Fill(dt);

        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        dt = crud.GetDataTable("Select Username, Password, Position , Firstname , Lastname , Status From UserAccounts Where Status = 'Active' ");
        string user = "";
        string pass = "";
        string pos = "";
        string name = "";
        string Lname = "";
        string status = "";
        Boolean checker = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            user = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString(); 
            pass = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
            bool Encryptflag = EncryptHelper.VerifyHash(txtPassword.Text, "SHA512", pass);
            pos = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString(); 
            name = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString();
            Lname = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString();
            status = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString();

            if (user.Equals(txtUsername.Text) && Encryptflag == true) 
            {
                    // Succesfully login
            }

            else 
            {
                checker = true;
            }
        }
        if (checker) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check your username or password.");
            txtPassword.Clear();
            txtPassword.Focus();          
            this.Show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you check if your query is returning any rows?

Comment: Your query is returning no rows because you're passing it the original password, but the data stores the *hashed* password.  You need to *hash* the entered password and *then* query the database.  (Or query the database by only the username and compare the hashed values in code.)  Also note that your expectations are entirely incorrect, you can not *decrypt* a *hashed* password.  That's the entire point of hashing it.

Comment: @David Ohh i see. Thank you so much sir. i will try doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is returning no rows because there are no matches in the data.  The database stores the *hashed* password.  (Which, incidentally, *can not* be decrypted.  So your expectations are false to begin with.)

You need to query the database only by the username, not by the password.  So remove the password clause from your `WHERE`.  *Then* you can continue to hash the entered password and compare the result of that operation with the value stored in the database.

This is by design.  You can not retrieve the original password after it has been hashed.  Instead, you hash entered passwords and see if the resulting hash string matches what's in the data.  If so, then the original passwords would have matched as well.

As a side note, your code is wide open to SQL Injection.  You should be using [query parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) instead of directly executing user input as if it were code.

---

**Edit:** So, for example, when selecting the user record by username you would omit the password clause:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from UserAccounts where Username = @Username", cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200); // "200" is a guess, use your actual column size and data type
cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value = txtUsername.Text;
```

This would pull the user record matching that username.  Then your logic would continue as it already does to hash the entered password and compare it with the stored already-hashed password.

Comment: Sir if it is not much trouble do you mind providing codes so i can better visualize? I am quite new sorry. But i understand the idea Thank you.

Comment: @StudentDev: I've edited the answer to include an example of the change.  Note that you also don't need to check `user.Equals(txtUsername.Text)` in your code because you *already* checked that in the SQL query.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. But what if i just want to type the password sir and not the username?

Comment: Then you should store your Username somewhere in your system or application, so you can still run the SqlCommand as David already explained.

Comment: Because in my query it is based on username, but in my password form there is new textbox for username, just for password.

Comment: @StudentDev: Then you'd get the username from wherever else you have that value available.  You have to *have* a value in order to *use* that value.

Comment: I have tried registering a new user with the same password. But the new hashed password is different though they are the same password. Looks like i cannot compare hashed passwords. Thank you sir i will try to work it out.

Comment: @StudentDev: You can compare hashed passwords if they are hashed *the same way*.  There are multiple hashing algorithms, and if you use a "salt" when hashing then there are literally infinite possibilities.  You have to use the *exact same* way of hashing or the results will be different.